# popup windows doesnt showed on oracle OUI

Tags: oracle, linux, installation

I have a fresh vm station with the recent centos 7 with GUI (everything is standard).
This problem happens on every popup window that appears on the oracle OUI, DBCA, ASMCA etc.. I'm using X to display the runInstallar (or whatever GUI command). sometimes I can enlarge the size of the window and revel the content of it but sometimes I don't. It's really frustrating and I'm sure many cross this issue before but I couldn't find it in google.
[image: example]